Canvas в QOPenGL
Делаю приложение, которое отображает спектрограмму (с синтетическими данными), используя qt, c++ и openGL.
Возник следующий вопрос, возможно ли в openGL использовать что то типо canvas, чтобы при вызове paintGL() не перерисовывать заново всю спектрограмму, а лишь добавлять новые значения

Рисуйте в текстуру, добавляя в нее новые значения. Затем все текстуру копируйте в свап чейн.

user7860670, спасибо)
Именно ваш способ использовал

Да, можно.

Более топорный вариант - заносите данные в текстуру (glTexImage2D) и используйте её для отрисовки.

Более технологичный - рисуйте данные в текстуру привязанную к кадровому буферу и потом выводите текстуру как обычно (https://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/)


И тот и другой вариант имеет смысл если отрисовка тяжелая и данных супер-много. Для вашего случая (судя по прошлым вопросам) это скорее всего излишне.
